# Authorize YouTube Data API for Android via OAuth2

Tags: android, youtube-data-api

I am trying to authorize with OAuth2 to use YouTube data API. I want to write a simple client for Android to have a possibility, for example, get lists of user subscriptions, playlist etc.
The problem is that each method I try (e.g. HTTP requests like `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions` or YouTube library `com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev120-1.19.0`), I get the same error:

> 401 Invalid Credentials

I do these steps:

1. Register app in Google's console. Enable YouTube Data API. Create OAuth credentials with my app package name and keystore.
2. Create Android API Key.

And here I have a lot of questions.

1. To have a possibility to get user subscriptions etc. do I have to register the app with OAuth2 credentials AND (?) Register API Key?
2. How can I use client_id and other data that is in client_secrets.json? How can I use this client_secrets.json at all? Do I need download it, and how to use it?

Because when I saw sample code, for example this:

```
GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(context.getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES));
            credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);

            YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(),
                    new JacksonFactory(), credential).setApplicationName(context.getString(R.string.app_name)).build();
```

Or used AccountManager and get token

```
 accountManager.getAuthToken(userAccount, "oauth2:" + mScope, null, (Activity) mContext,
            new OnTokenAcquired(), null);
where mScope="https://gdata.youtube.com"
```

and then use it this way

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&maxResults=10&mine=true&key={here is my key}&access_token= ya29.bgJa5J8LHHu0Mu3P87mbPY9gfhSFzWUHh8gCw022FC6yfMO6GfVHveYr_BG1-HnWF-jpd-IDcGGVrF3gEf4UhSHPSrV76RAwqd4V17ixn72s1Xl6a0wQ4FVDz3cEZjUEN80o
```

I get the same authError error every time (in short):

> "code": 401,
>      "message": "Invalid Credentials"

What I am doing wrong? How to use client_id in variant 1 and 2. Is it necessary? Because I think it is the reason why it does not work.